# JQuery Layout plugin and calculating resize

Tags: jquery, events, layout, resize

We are thinking about using the JQuery Layout plugin for our layout. It seems to be working perfectly except for one thing:

Inside my center element I have a div which contains elements that has to be resized manually with JavaScript. But for some reason this does not trigger $('#myDiv').resize(). I can see that #myDiv changes size when I resize the sliders, but still the event is not triggered. Anyone knows why?

As extra information: #myDiv is has absolute positioning. Perhaps this is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `your_layout.sizePane(pane, size)` to notify your layout. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750787/jquery-ui-layout-resize-a-pane-does-not-refresh-the-rest)
I faced with the same problem.