# jQuery UI Layout resize a pane does not refresh the rest

Tags: jquery, layout, jquery-plugins

I created a jqPlot on the east pane. And I change the size of the pane to allow enough space for the chart. However, seems some part of the layout did not get refreshed at all. How do I notify the rest of the layout and make it refresh? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use sizePane to let your layout know you just resized it.

```
var your_layout = jQuery("#your_container").layout({...});
...
jQuery("#RightPane").width('400px');
your_layout.sizePane("east", 400);
```

Here is where the original answer coming from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jquery-ui-layout/u6BsKaArFNY